# NGINX and local-hosted custom domain names

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm setting up a nginx webserver locally with this config:

`server {
    server_name im;`

```
access_log /var/www/im/website.access_log;
error_log /var/www/im/website.error_log;

root /var/www/im;
index index.php index.htm index.html;

location ~ .php$ {
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/im/$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

I want to access the local-hosted site with "im/", instead, i get a "not found". The only thing that works is "localhost". Is this possible? What should i correct/add to my config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name needs to resolve from the system -- you'll need to add the name to your `/etc/hosts` file.